# Got empty string - Qt

Tags: c++, string, qt, return

I have funktion in class that returns a `QString` value with the code below:

```
QString mini_artikel::get_bez()const
{
    return (m_bez);
}
```

I initailise `m_bez` with this code:

```
bool mini_artikel_transporter::loadArtikelData(int artikelnummer)
{

    mini_artikel ma;
    DB_ArtikelStamm as_db;

    if(m_as_t==nullptr)
        m_as_t= new DB_ArtikelStammTransporter(conWWS);


    if(!m_as_t->load_dbArtikelStamm(&as_db,artikelnummer))
    {
        critical()<<"mini_artikel_transporter::loadArtikelData("<<artikelnummer<<"): Failed";
        return(false);
    }

    ma.m_bez=as_db.get_bez();
    return (true);
}
```

and fill my string with this function in another cpp file`

```
if(ma_transporter.loadArtikel(b.get_artikelkorr()))
           str_bez=ma.get_bez();
```

The problem is i got always `str_bez=""`! What i do wrong?

Comment: Qt Creator is not a compiler or a language. It's jus an IDE. Fix your question title.

Comment: And I would add: it's "Qt", not "QT" like everybody here thinks

Comment: check what 'as_db.get_bez()' returns ??

Comment: You have a bug in your code. Luckily, Qt creator has a nice user interface for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not Qt, but your code. You obviously have a bug.

The function load_dbArtikelStamm doesn't initialise the first argument, DB_ArtikelStamm as_db, properly making the call to as_db.get_bez() return an empty string.